# Не отображает изображения на сайте

Tags: php, сервер

Такая проблема -не отображает изображения на сайте . Перепробовал много способов - и в ту же директорию вставлял изображение и в корень сайта. Использую встроенный веб сервер php . Сервер пишет 127.0.0.1:42852 [404]: /home/yura/PhpstormProjects/ProductReview/src/Views/follow.jpeg - No such file or directory хотя в этой директории есть данный файл. Это я скопировал путь самой картинки (Сopy Path) /home/yura/PhpstormProjects/ProductReview/src/Views/follow.jpeg

test.php и img на уровне index.php

test.php

```
<img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="no">
<?php
phpinfo();
```

В папке img один файл img2.jpg который спокойно открывается IDE и phpinfo отрабатыват 
htaaccess

```
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: вот что вам точно не надо, дак это хранить изображения в `src\Views`. Чтобы изображение на сайте отобразить надо указывать путь относительный корня сайта. И соответственно сам изображение должно быть где то в корне сайта или дочерних директориях.

Comment: положил на уровень index.php папку img в нее файл img1.jpg то  же самое... Отображает только значение alt

Comment: Код может стоит прикрепить на всякий случай ?

Comment: прикрепил тестовый код

Comment: "отображает только значение alt"  - а у вас в htaccess не стоит случайно запрет на отображение не со своего ресурса, и там, по недосмотру, указан не ваш ресурс?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. А где находится .htaaccess встроенного сервера? Я свой закомментировал , перезагрузил и снова только alt

Comment: `.htaccess` в студию

Comment: не пробовали убрать сторонние функции и прочий php код и попробовать просто оставить `<img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="no">` ?

Comment: кинул файл htaaccess

Comment: попробовал убрать все кроме image - та же история , но когда в PhpStorm есть открыть в браузере - то картинка открывается

Comment: Попробовал и так <?php
echo '<img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="no">'; результат тот же

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```html
<img src="{{ url('/img/img2.jpg'); }}" alt="no">
```

или

```js
<img src="<? echo url('/img/img2.jpg'); ?>" alt="no">
```

```css
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем огромное спасибо за уделенное внимание. Чисто случайно сменил права на 755 и вуаля все заработало